# Haskell - how can I check if number is Double/Float?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, integer

I would like to do smth like:

```
x `mod` 1.0 == 0 // => int
```

but it seems mod works only for int... help!
EDIT:
I am trying to check if given number is triangle, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_number so my idea was to check if n1 is Int...

> (n*(n+1))/2 = s => n1 = (-1 +sqrt(1 +
>   8s))/2

Comment: huh? you mean checking if a `Float` is not a round integer?

Comment: Doing this kind of thing with Floats is a bad idea in general because rounding errors can so easily trip you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Total edit:**

Okay, I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

- First, anything modulo 1 is going to be zero, because the modulo function only makes sense on integers. If you want to take the modulo of a fractional type you can convert to an integer first. **Edit**: Although for what it's worth, `Data.Fixed` does have a `mod'` function for non-integral values.
- I also don't know what you mean by "check if n1 is Int". Either it is or it isn't; you don't need to check at run time. **Edit**: Okay, I see now that you're just checking to see if a value has a fractional component. Paul Johnson correctly points out above that it's wise to be careful doing such things with floating point values.
- If you want to mix `mod` and `sqrt` operations in the same calculation, you'll have to manually convert between appropriate types. `fromIntegral` will convert any integer type into any number type, `floor`, `ceiling`, and `round` will convert fractional types to integral types.

Comment: Check my edit plz, I am try to check if given number is Triangle Number

Comment: Thx for clue, now I did (ceiling x == floor x) and it seems to work ;) (false if x has factional part)

Comment: @MMM: Okay, I'm still confused, but glad I could help...?

Comment: Why confused? My problem was: user give number s, so I check if for s = n(n + 1)/2, n is natural, with none factional part, if so, given "s" is Triangle number... am I right?:)

Comment: @camccann: regarding "modulo function only makes sense on integers": http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolynomialRemainder.html, and in Python you can use modulo like `7.2 % 5` and it might be useful for calculating what change you need to give in coins etc.

Comment: @yairchu: A fair point on polynomials, though I don't know if I've heard the term "modulo" applied to that case. I expect other algebraic structures support something analogous, as well. The Python example is a bit silly, though, and really stretches the definition of "modular arithmetic". Then again, programming languages have been misusing that term for a while now...

Comment: @camccann: Python's "extension" of modulo makes sense as it is the only one that satisfies the rule `x == x//d + x%d`. I can see how it is in a way weird as unlike the other modulos it's not `a -> a -> a`

Comment: @camccann: btw, a use case for Python's fractional modulo: let's say you are playing a sampled drum-loop. to know the current position in the loop, you can use Python's modulo

Answer (score 7):

To determine whether a certain `Float` or `Double` is indistinguishable from an `Integer` in Haskell, use `floor` and `ceiling` together. Something like:

```
if floor n == ceiling n
  then "It was some integer."
  else "It's between integers."
```

There might also be some fancy stuff you can do with the float's representation in binary, exposed by the RealFloat typeclass:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3ARealFloat

Comment: You were too late, I found that solutions themselfes, check my comment above ;)

Comment: Where you say 'themselfes' I think you mean 'myself'.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to check if a number is triangular is to generate a list of triangular numbers and then see if your candidate is in it.  Since this is a learning problem I'm going to give hints rather than the answer.

Use a list comprehension to generate the triangular numbers.

Since they will be in order you can find out if you have gone past them.

An alternative approach if you are working with big numbers would be to use a binary search to narrow down the number of rows that might give rise to your candidate.

Comment: But that list will be inifinty? Haskell stop searching themselfs when nummber will be bigger than searching one?

Comment: Yes, the list will be infinite.  And no, Haskell won't realise this unless you tell it.  So you need to figure out how to make the search terminate.

Comment: By which measure is that way better? It's certainly more expensive than just using the formula. It's also almost certainly more code.

Comment: Floating point numbers can be tricky, especially when you are comparing them.  It would be very easy to end up with 3.999999982 instead of 4.0, at which point your algorithm fails.  Even if it seems to work most of the time, you never know if the next case is going to fail.  So if you are dealing with integers then its best to find a way of doing the whole thing with integers.